# Why would a stack view is altering equally spaced horizontal buttons to equal spaced buttons in a box?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

So I have a straightforward stack view.  3 buttons are evenly distributed on the horizontal plane.  However, the stack view is also unexpectedly extending the width of the stack to create an unfinished dimension of auto layout, which ends up creating boxes in my previews.  The stack view is anchored to the leading, top, and trailing edges by 20 pixels.  The text of each button is only size 20.  I am unsure what I have missed and would appreciate any thoughts regarding a possible fix.  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please attach a picture of the attributes inspector of the stack view in the storyboard (mainly, the top stack view portion).

Comment: Uploaded a wider screenshot!

Comment: Try setting a height constraint on the stack view itself.

Comment: How would I go about that?  (Sorry, beginner).  Would I control drag my stack view or set that in my size inspector?  or other?

Comment: Click the stack view, click the 3rd button from the left (on the bottom right, has a square in the middle), click the height checkbox, click add constraints.

Comment: You sir, are a scholar and a gentlemen.  Thank you! It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I was unsure at first (which is why I posted it as a comment originally), all you have to do is add a height constraint to the stack view, otherwise it will have an ambiguous height. For some weird reason, the buttons don't maintain their intrinsic content size when inside stack views.

Comment: I would have expected the font size to delegate the overall height of the stack view, so I agree, it's unexpected.  Either way, Thank you!